# Cannot implement YouTube Android Player API with Mvvm Model xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, youtube-data-api

I need to use **YouTubePlayerView** to play Youtube Video in my **mvvm crossplatform** project. The problem is: my view needs to inherit 2 classes while C# does not allow multiple inheritance:

**VideoDetailView.cs**

```
 public class VideoDetailView : MvxAppCompatActivity, YouTubeBaseActivity
    {
    }
```

1. YouTubeBaseActivity to use Google Player API, to use a YouTubePlayerView, your activity must extend YouTubeBaseActivity.
2. MvxAppCompatActivity to be able to bind View with ViewModel.

Have been stuck in this issue for couple days, I need help!

Thanks

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but this is the ViewModel right??

Comment: this is ViewModel @G.hakim

Comment: Then why are you inheriting this with `YouTubeBaseActivity` i mean i am confused

Comment: for using Youtube Player in the view, I need to extend YouTubeBaseActivity from Google @G.hakim

Comment: I couldnt find any better solution for playing video in Xamarin Android App. As I know to create an Mvvm model, the view need to inherit class MvxViewController @G.hakim

Comment: Isn't that for iOS i mean i am sure its for iOS!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188871/discussion-between-vyclarks-and-g-hakim).

Comment: Anyone with an answer ? I am facing the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

To implement this feature, you can create **MvxYouTubeBaseActivity**:

```
MvxYouTubeBaseActivity : YouTubeBaseActivity, IMvxEventSourceActivity, IMvxAndroidView
{
        protected MvxYouTubeBaseActivity()
        {
            BindingContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext(this, this);
            this.AddEventListeners();
        }

        //Implement all methods from IMvxEventSourceActivity, IMvxAndroidView
}
```

And create **MvxYouTubeBaseActivity<TViewModel.>**:

```
public abstract class MvxYouTubeBaseActivity<TViewModel>: MvxYouTubeBaseActivity, IMvxAndroidView<TViewModel>
        where TViewModel : class, IMvxViewModel
    {
        protected MvxYouTubeBaseActivity(IntPtr ptr, JniHandleOwnership ownership)
            : base(ptr, ownership)
        {
        }

        protected MvxYouTubeBaseActivity()
        {
        }

        public new TViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get => (TViewModel)base.ViewModel;
            set => base.ViewModel = value;
        }
    }
```

That's all, you can use it with MVVMCross